# Reviewing first posts that are answers or late answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-system

When reviewing first posts that are answers or late answers to questions that have existing answers I invariably go to the original question to see these answers since I want to check if these new answers duplicate content, etc.

Can we please have these other answers appear automatically when reviewing or can someone give me the reason why they are not?